How to sort array of tuples alphabetically only based on the first item of the tuple in nim?
if i have a sequence
let my_seq = @[("a", "hello"), ("c", "world"), ("b", "to")]
how can i sort this so that it returns:
let my_seq = @[("a", "hello"), ("b", "to")] ("c", "world")
tried to google it but theres no resources for nim basically

Re "theres no resources for nim": The best resource is Nim's own documentation. Specifically in your case, the one for the std/algorithm module.

Use the sort procedure from the standard library. If needed, customize it by also providing a comparison function that defines how the items should be compared to each other, and returns an integer indicating their order.
Simple case:
import std/algorithm

var my_seq = @[("a", "hello"), ("c", "world"), ("b", "to")]

my_seq.sort()

echo(my_seq)

Demo
Example comparing the tuples just by their first element (at position 0):
import std/algorithm

var my_seq = @[("a", "hello"), ("c", "world"), ("b", "to")]

proc myCmp(x, y: (string, string)): int = cmp(x[0], y[0])

my_seq.sort(myCmp)

echo(my_seq)

Demo
Note that I've changed let to var to make the sequence mutable. If you wanted to keep the original sequence immutable, and just based on that define a new one, use sorted instead:
import std/algorithm

let my_seq = @[("a", "hello"), ("c", "world"), ("b", "to")]

let my_seq2 = sorted(my_seq)  # or sorted(my_seq, cmp)

echo(my_seq2)

Demo
All of them output:
@[("a", "hello"), ("b", "to"), ("c", "world")]

